# Python - Sign encoded transaction and broadcast

Tags: transactions, python, sign

I am using an API that builds a TX for me. I get the following fields:

```
{
        "encoded_transaction": "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",
        "mint": "7gc9CRNqQF8v8Fo6r5mdFw26W2vaqdTUdWdXhi72rnBu",
        "signers": [
            "6onZzXdurac4ykUCqLewQLDPwfmgHRU9Cu9k6A6anPtx",
            "6onZzXdurac4ykUCqLewQLDPwfmgHRU9Cu9k6A6anPtx"
        ]
    }
```

Using my private key, how can I sign that and broadcast the tx, using Python?

Comment: Sidenote: that transaction appears to require two signers, and one of them isn't listed in the code sample you've provided: https://t.ly/_SzvT

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to decode the transaction from base64 into bytes, deserialize the partially signed transaction from that, and then sign / send it with your private key.

Assuming you have the response and your private key, you can do:

```
import solana.transaction as txlib
from base64 import b64decode
from solana.rpc.api import Client

rpc_client = Client('...endpoint here...')
private_key = '... your private key here... ';
response = '... get the response from the server... ';

wire_txn = b64decode(response['encoded_transaction'])
txn = txlib.Transaction.deserialize(wire_txn)
resp = rpc_client.send_transaction(txn, private_key)
```

Adapated from the tests in https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/tree/master